# How do I decode this Json array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

How do I decode this json data using php to get individual values.

{"Alpha":["A","B","C","D","E","F"],"Beta":["1","2","3"],"Gamma": ["a","b","c"]}

Comment: `php.net/json_encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php has a function called [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode%20json_decode)

```
$json = '{"Alpha":["A","B","C","D","E","F"],"Beta":["1","2","3"],"Gamma": ["a","b","c"]}';

$json_array = json_decode($json,TRUE); // personally I prefer arrays which the TRUE adds

$alpha = $json_array['Alpha'];

$first_alpha_value = $alpha[0];

printf("A == %s\n",$first_alpha_value);
```